# How to use the "< >" in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can I use the < and > as text in React? I am trying to use it for my portfolio?

[image]

Comment: You don't. Plain text is not a component, so it should not be within `<>`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use [HTML entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

> Reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities.

| Result | Description | Entity Name | Entity Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| < | less than | `&lt;` | `&#60;` |
| > | greater than | `&gt;` | `&#62;` |

HTML

```
<div className="left-column">&lt;Lorenzo Codes
```

Answer (score 3):

`<div>{"<"}  {">"} </div>`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<div className="left-column">{'<Lorenzo Codes'}
```

Comment: My opinion is quite the opposite. I think that is far from easy to understand that `&lt;` it's equal to `<`